# Automatic image slider with customized bullets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
   <body>
<div id="slide">
      <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div class="mySlides fade"> <img src="images/Image01.png"> </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade"> <img src="images/Image02.png"> </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade"> <img src="images/Image03.png"> </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade"> <img src="images/Image04.png"> </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade"> <img src="images/Image05.png"> </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade"> <img src="images/Image06.png"> </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    <div class="dots"> 
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(6)"></span>
   </div
</body>
```

i am trying to customize the bullets in the slider as show in the image .can any one help me.

[image]

Comment: sorry for missing script.

Comment: use slick slider it gives us a customization option http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: i have done with automatic image sliding. i am trying to customize the bullets of slider.@zyruscalligraph

Comment: Please go read [ask], and [mcve]. If you tried something and it did not work, then you need to show us what you actually tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS pseudo-element `:before` or `:after` on your `.dot`.

There are many ways to do it, this is just one approach.

```css
.dot {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.dot:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: brown;
  width:10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 1px;
}

.dot.active:before {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="dots"> 
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
          <span class="dot active" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(6)"></span>
   </div>
```

Comment: that i have done but  its not getting changed for each slide.

Comment: What are you mean "not getting changed"?

Comment: i mean .i am using automatic image changing slider . you just see this website i am trying do slider bullets like this https://mobirise.com/bootstrap-carousel/

Comment: You have to set a class, like `active` when the bullet point is the current. then you can style it.

Comment: even i have tried  the active class with background color and defining height and width but still its not working and i have called active class in the script but still not working

Comment: It is hard to guess what is going on on something you did not put on your question... My answer is answering your question, and as per the code snippet it is working. If you have a different question update your question or create a new one... also read [How to aks](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and